# What does tf.nn.embedding_lookup function do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, word-embedding, nlp

```
tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params, ids, partition_strategy='mod', name=None)
```

I cannot understand the duty of this function. Is it like a lookup table? Which means to return the parameters corresponding to each id (in ids)?

For instance, in the `skip-gram` model if we use `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)`, then for each `train_input` it finds the correspond embedding?

Comment: "Is it like a lookup table?" tldr - Yes. For each x (ids) give me the associate y (params).

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`embedding_lookup` function retrieves rows of the `params` tensor. The behavior is similar to using indexing with arrays in numpy. E.g.

```
matrix = np.random.random([1024, 64])  # 64-dimensional embeddings
ids = np.array([0, 5, 17, 33])
print matrix[ids]  # prints a matrix of shape [4, 64]
```

`params` argument can be also a list of tensors in which case the `ids` will be distributed among the tensors. For example, given a list of 3 tensors `[2, 64]`, the default behavior is that they will represent `ids`: `[0, 3]`, `[1, 4]`, `[2, 5]`.

`partition_strategy` controls the way how the `ids` are distributed among the list. The partitioning is useful for larger scale problems when the matrix might be too large to keep in one piece.

Comment: Why would they call it this way and not `select_rows`?

Comment: @LenarHoyt because this idea of a lookup comes from Word Embeddings.
and the "rows" are the representations (embeddings) of the words, into a vector space -- and are useful in an of themself. Often more so than the actual network.

Comment: How does tensorflow learn the embedding structure? Does this function manage that process too?

Comment: @vgoklani, no, `embedding_lookup` simply provides a convenient (and parallel) way to retrieve embeddings corresponding to id in `ids`. The `params` tensor is usually a tf variable that is learned as part of the training process -- a tf variable whose components are used, directly or indirectly, in a loss function (such as `tf.l2_loss`) which is optimized by an optimizer (such as `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`).

Comment: @LenarHoyt select_"parallel"_rows

Comment: @ToussaintLouverture What do you mean by parallel?

Comment: @Rafał Józefowicz  Why "the default behavior is that they will represent ids: [0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]."? Could you explain?

Comment: Just to clarify, the exact same functionality can be performed using tf.gather, correct?

Comment: So, this function is used only to get embeddings suitable to the input batches? If that is the case, why not just create embeddings that suits the batch size?

Comment: Can someone explain  the implementation of it ?
Like how it is parallel and how are the keys retrieved from memory ?

Comment: Is it trainable?

Comment: `For example, given a list of 3 tensors [2, 64], the default behavior is that they will represent ids: [0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]. ` - need explanation.

Answer (score 233):

Yes, this function is hard to understand, until you get the point.

In its simplest form, it is similar to `tf.gather`. It returns the elements of `params` according to the indexes specified by `ids`.

For example (assuming you are inside `tf.InteractiveSession()`)

```
params = tf.constant([10,20,30,40])
ids = tf.constant([0,1,2,3])
print tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params,ids).eval()
```

would return `[10 20 30 40]`, because the first element (index 0) of params is `10`, the second element of params (index 1) is `20`, etc.

Similarly,

```
params = tf.constant([10,20,30,40])
ids = tf.constant([1,1,3])
print tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params,ids).eval()
```

would return `[20 20 40]`.

But `embedding_lookup` is more than that. The `params` argument can be a **list** of tensors, rather than a single tensor.

```
params1 = tf.constant([1,2])
params2 = tf.constant([10,20])
ids = tf.constant([2,0,2,1,2,3])
result = tf.nn.embedding_lookup([params1, params2], ids)
```

In such a case, the indexes, specified in `ids`, correspond to elements of tensors according to a **partition strategy**, where the default partition strategy is 'mod'.

In the 'mod' strategy, index 0 corresponds to the first element of the first tensor in the list. Index 1 corresponds to the **first** element of the **second** tensor. Index 2 corresponds to the **first** element of the **third** tensor, and so on. Simply index `i` corresponds to the first element of the (i+1)th tensor , for all the indexes `0..(n-1)`, assuming params is a list of `n` tensors.

Now, index `n` cannot correspond to tensor n+1, because the list `params` contains only `n` tensors. So index `n` corresponds to the **second** element of the first tensor. Similarly, index `n+1` corresponds to the second element of the second tensor, etc.

So, in the code

```
params1 = tf.constant([1,2])
params2 = tf.constant([10,20])
ids = tf.constant([2,0,2,1,2,3])
result = tf.nn.embedding_lookup([params1, params2], ids)
```

index 0 corresponds to the first element of the first tensor: 1

index 1 corresponds to the first element of the second tensor: 10

index 2 corresponds to the second element of the first tensor: 2

index 3 corresponds to the second element of the second tensor: 20

Thus, the result would be:

```
[ 2  1  2 10  2 20]
```

Comment: a note: you can use `partition_strategy='div'`, and would get `[10,  1, 10,  2, 10, 20]`, i.e. `id=1` is the second element of the first param. Basically:

`partition_strategy=mod` (default) 
`id%len(params)`: index of the param in params
`id//len(params)`: index of the element in the above param
`partition_strategy=*div*` the other way around

Comment: @asher-stern could you explain why "mod" strategy is default? seems that "div" strategy is more similar to the standard tensor slicing(select-rows by given indices). Is there some performance issues in case of "div"?

Answer (score 49):

Yes, the purpose of [**`tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) function is to perform a *lookup* in the *embedding matrix* and return the embeddings (or in simple terms the vector representation) of words.

A simple embedding matrix (of shape: **`vocabulary_size x embedding_dimension`**) would look like below. (i.e. each *word* will be represented by a *vector* of numbers; hence the name *word2vec*)

---

**Embedding Matrix**

```
the 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862
like 0.36808 0.20834 -0.22319 0.046283 0.20098 0.27515 -0.77127 -0.76804
between 0.7503 0.71623 -0.27033 0.20059 -0.17008 0.68568 -0.061672 -0.054638
did 0.042523 -0.21172 0.044739 -0.19248 0.26224 0.0043991 -0.88195 0.55184
just 0.17698 0.065221 0.28548 -0.4243 0.7499 -0.14892 -0.66786 0.11788
national -1.1105 0.94945 -0.17078 0.93037 -0.2477 -0.70633 -0.8649 -0.56118
day 0.11626 0.53897 -0.39514 -0.26027 0.57706 -0.79198 -0.88374 0.30119
country -0.13531 0.15485 -0.07309 0.034013 -0.054457 -0.20541 -0.60086 -0.22407
under 0.13721 -0.295 -0.05916 -0.59235 0.02301 0.21884 -0.34254 -0.70213
such 0.61012 0.33512 -0.53499 0.36139 -0.39866 0.70627 -0.18699 -0.77246
second -0.29809 0.28069 0.087102 0.54455 0.70003 0.44778 -0.72565 0.62309
```

---

I split the above embedding matrix and loaded only the *words* in `vocab` which will be our vocabulary and the corresponding vectors in `emb` array.

```
vocab = ['the','like','between','did','just','national','day','country','under','such','second']

emb = np.array([[0.418, 0.24968, -0.41242, 0.1217, 0.34527, -0.044457, -0.49688, -0.17862],
   [0.36808, 0.20834, -0.22319, 0.046283, 0.20098, 0.27515, -0.77127, -0.76804],
   [0.7503, 0.71623, -0.27033, 0.20059, -0.17008, 0.68568, -0.061672, -0.054638],
   [0.042523, -0.21172, 0.044739, -0.19248, 0.26224, 0.0043991, -0.88195, 0.55184],
   [0.17698, 0.065221, 0.28548, -0.4243, 0.7499, -0.14892, -0.66786, 0.11788],
   [-1.1105, 0.94945, -0.17078, 0.93037, -0.2477, -0.70633, -0.8649, -0.56118],
   [0.11626, 0.53897, -0.39514, -0.26027, 0.57706, -0.79198, -0.88374, 0.30119],
   [-0.13531, 0.15485, -0.07309, 0.034013, -0.054457, -0.20541, -0.60086, -0.22407],
   [ 0.13721, -0.295, -0.05916, -0.59235, 0.02301, 0.21884, -0.34254, -0.70213],
   [ 0.61012, 0.33512, -0.53499, 0.36139, -0.39866, 0.70627, -0.18699, -0.77246 ],
   [ -0.29809, 0.28069, 0.087102, 0.54455, 0.70003, 0.44778, -0.72565, 0.62309 ]])


emb.shape
# (11, 8)
```

---

**Embedding Lookup in TensorFlow**

Now we will see how can we perform *embedding lookup* for some arbitrary input sentence.

```
In [54]: from collections import OrderedDict

# embedding as TF tensor (for now constant; could be tf.Variable() during training)
In [55]: tf_embedding = tf.constant(emb, dtype=tf.float32)

# input for which we need the embedding
In [56]: input_str = "like the country"

# build index based on our `vocabulary`
In [57]: word_to_idx = OrderedDict({w:vocab.index(w) for w in input_str.split() if w in vocab})

# lookup in embedding matrix & return the vectors for the input words
In [58]: tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tf_embedding, list(word_to_idx.values())).eval()
Out[58]: 
array([[ 0.36807999,  0.20834   , -0.22318999,  0.046283  ,  0.20097999,
         0.27515   , -0.77126998, -0.76804   ],
       [ 0.41800001,  0.24968   , -0.41242   ,  0.1217    ,  0.34527001,
        -0.044457  , -0.49687999, -0.17862   ],
       [-0.13530999,  0.15485001, -0.07309   ,  0.034013  , -0.054457  ,
        -0.20541   , -0.60086   , -0.22407   ]], dtype=float32)
```

Observe how we got the *embeddings* from our original embedding matrix (with words) using the *indices of words* in our vocabulary.

Usually, such an embedding lookup is performed by the first layer (called *Embedding layer*) which then passes these embeddings to RNN/LSTM/GRU layers for further processing.

---

*Side Note*: Usually the vocabulary will also have a special `unk` token. So, if a token from our input sentence is not present in our vocabulary, then the index corresponding to **`unk`** will be looked up in the embedding matrix.

---

**P.S.** Note that `embedding_dimension` is a hyperparameter that one has to tune for their application but popular models like **[Word2Vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec)** and **[GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/)** uses `300` dimension vector for representing each word.

**Bonus Reading** [word2vec skip-gram model](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/)

Answer (score 18):

Here's an image depicting the process of embedding lookup.

[image: Image: Embedding lookup process]


Concisely, it gets the corresponding rows of a embedding layer, specified by a list of IDs and provide that as a tensor. It is achieved through the following process.

1. Define a placeholder `lookup_ids = tf.placeholder([10])`
2. Define a embedding layer `embeddings = tf.Variable([100,10],...)`
3. Define the tensorflow operation `embed_lookup = tf.embedding_lookup(embeddings, lookup_ids)`
4. Get the results by running `lookup = session.run(embed_lookup, feed_dict={lookup_ids:[95,4,14]})`

Answer (score 7):

When the params tensor is in high dimensions, the ids only refers to top dimension. Maybe it's obvious to most of people but I have to run the following code to understand that:

```
embeddings = tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]],[[11,11],[12,12],[13,13],[14,14]],
                          [[21,21],[22,22],[23,23],[24,24]]])
ids=tf.constant([0,2,1])
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, ids, partition_strategy='div')

with tf.Session() as session:
    result = session.run(embed)
    print (result)
```

Just trying the 'div' strategy and for one tensor, it makes no difference.

Here is the output:

```
[[[ 1  1]
  [ 2  2]
  [ 3  3]
  [ 4  4]]

 [[21 21]
  [22 22]
  [23 23]
  [24 24]]

 [[11 11]
  [12 12]
  [13 13]
  [14 14]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at it is , assume that you flatten out the tensors to one dimensional array, and then you are performing a lookup

(eg) Tensor0=[1,2,3], Tensor1=[4,5,6], Tensor2=[7,8,9]

The flattened out tensor will be as follows
[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]

Now when you do a lookup of [0,3,4,1,7] it will yeild [1,2,5,4,6]

(i,e) if lookup value is 7 for example , and we have 3 tensors (or a tensor with 3 rows) then,

7 / 3 : (Reminder is 1, Quotient is 2) So 2nd element of Tensor1 will be shown, which is 6

Answer (score 3):

Since I was also intrigued by this function, I'll give my two cents.

The way I see it in the 2D case is just as a matrix multiplication (it's easy to generalize to other dimensions).

Consider a vocabulary with N symbols.
Then, you can represent a symbol ***x*** as a vector of dimensions Nx1, one-hot-encoded.

But you want a representation of this symbol not as a vector of Nx1, but as one with dimensions Mx1, called ***y***.

So, to transform ***x*** into ***y***, you can use and embedding matrix **E**, with dimensions MxN:

***y*** = **E** ***x***.

This is essentially what tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params, ids, ...) is doing, with the nuance that *ids* are just one number that represents the position of the 1 in the one-hot-encoded vector ***x***.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Asher Stern's answer,
 `params` is
  interpreted as a **partitioning** of a large embedding tensor. It can be a  single tensor representing the complete embedding tensor,
      or a list of X tensors all of same shape except for the first dimension,
      representing sharded embedding tensors.

The function `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` is written considering the fact that embedding (params) will be large. Therefore we need `partition_strategy`.

Answer (score 0):

The existing explanations are not enough.
The main purpose of this function is to efficiently retrieve the vectors for each word in a given sequence of word indices. Suppose we have the following matrix of embeddings:

```
embds = np.array([[0.2, 0.32,0.9],
        [0.8, 0.62,0.19],
        [0.0, -0.22,-1.9],
        [1.2, 2.32,6.0],
        [0.11, 0.10,5.9]])
```

Let's say we have the following sequences of word indices:

```
data=[[0,1],
     [3,4]]
```

Now to get the corresponding embedding for each word in our data:

```
tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    embds, data
)
```

out:

```
array([[[0.2 , 0.32, 0.9 ],
        [0.8 , 0.62, 0.19]],

       [[1.2 , 2.32, 6.  ],
        [0.11, 0.1 , 5.9 ]]])>
```

**Note** If embds are not an array or tensor, the output will not be like this (I won't go into details). For example, if embds were a list, the output would be:

```
array([[0.2 , 0.32],
       [0.8 , 0.62]], dtype=float32)>
```