# How do I select certain columns of a 2D tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

As generalized slicing is being worked on in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206), what would be the best way to achieve an op gathering columns of a 2D tensor (matrix)? For example, for tensor `t`:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

and indices [1,3], I would like to get:

```
2 4
6 8
```

which is equivalent to numpy `t[:, [1,3]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, I created a workaround by flattening the input and using `gather`:

```py
def gather_cols(params, indices, name=None):
    """Gather columns of a 2D tensor.

    Args:
        params: A 2D tensor.
        indices: A 1D tensor. Must be one of the following types: ``int32``, ``int64``.
        name: A name for the operation (optional).

    Returns:
        A 2D Tensor. Has the same type as ``params``.
    """
    with tf.op_scope([params, indices], name, "gather_cols") as scope:
        # Check input
        params = tf.convert_to_tensor(params, name="params")
        indices = tf.convert_to_tensor(indices, name="indices")
        try:
            params.get_shape().assert_has_rank(2)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('\'params\' must be 2D.')
        try:
            indices.get_shape().assert_has_rank(1)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('\'indices\' must be 1D.')

        # Define op
        p_shape = tf.shape(params)
        p_flat = tf.reshape(params, [-1])
        i_flat = tf.reshape(tf.reshape(tf.range(0, p_shape[0]) * p_shape[1],
                                       [-1, 1]) + indices, [-1])
        return tf.reshape(tf.gather(p_flat, i_flat),
                          [p_shape[0], -1])
```

Which for:

```py
params = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],
                      [4, 5, 6]])
indices = [0, 2]
op = gather_cols(params, indices)
```

produces the expected output:

```
[[1 3]
 [4 6]]
```

Answer (score 26):

Meanwhile the `gather` method has an `axis` parameter.

```
import tensorflow as tf
params = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
indices = [0,2]
op = tf.gather(params, indices, axis=1)
```

produces the output

```
[[1 3]
 [4 6]]
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a function named [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params, ind)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870614/what-does-tf-nn-embedding-lookup-function-do)  which retrieves the **rows** of the `params` tensor.

To achieve what you want, we can first transpose the tensor `t` from which you want to select certain columns from. Then look up the rows of `tf.transpose(t)` (columns of `t`). After the selection, we transpose the result back.

```
import tensorflow as tf


t = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], 
                 [4, 5, 6]])
ind = tf.constant([0, 2])

result = tf.transpose(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tf.transpose(t), ind))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))
```

Comment: Why not just using gather if you want to transpose? I though that transposing is expensive in TF.