# TensorFlow Embedding Lookup

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, recurrent-neural-network, language-model

I am trying to learn how to build RNN for Speech Recognition using TensorFlow. As a start, I wanted to try out some example models put up on TensorFlow page [TF-RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/index.html)

As per what was advised, I had taken some time to understand how word IDs are embedded into a dense representation (Vector Representation) by working through the basic version of word2vec model code. I had an understanding of what `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` actually does, until I actually encountered the same function being used with two dimensional array in [TF-RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) `ptb_word_lm.py`, when it did not make sense any more.

#### what I though `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` does:

Given a 2-d array `params`, and a 1-d array `ids`, function `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` fetches rows from params, corresponding to the indices given in `ids`, which holds with the dimension of output it is returning.

#### What I am confused about:

When tried with same params, and 2-d array `ids`, `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` returns 3-d array, instead of 2-d which I do not understand why.

I looked up the manual for [Embedding Lookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#embedding_lookup), but I still find it difficult to understand how the partitioning works, and the result that is returned. I recently tried some simple example with `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` and it appears that it returns different values each time. Is this behaviour due to the randomness involved in partitioning ?

Please help me understand how `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` works, and why is used in both `word2vec_basic.py`, and `ptb_word_lm.py` i.e., what is the purpose of even using them ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does tf.nn.embedding\_lookup function do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870614/what-does-tf-nn-embedding-lookup-function-do)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is already an answer on what does `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870614/what-does-tf-nn-embedding-lookup-function-do).

---

> When tried with same params, and 2-d array ids, tf.nn.embedding_lookup returns 3-d array, instead of 2-d which I do not understand why.

When you had a 1-D list of ids `[0, 1]`, the function would return a list of embeddings `[embedding_0, embedding_1]` where `embedding_0` is an array of shape `embedding_size`. For instance the list of ids could be a batch of words.

Now, you have a **matrix** of ids, or a list of list of ids. For instance, you now have a batch of **sentences**, i.e. a batch of list of words, i.e. a list of list of words.

If your list of sentences is: `[[0, 1], [0, 3]]` (sentence 1 is `[0, 1]`, sentence 2 is `[0, 3]`), the function will compute a matrix of embeddings, which will be of shape `[2, 2, embedding_size]`and will look like:

```
[[embedding_0, embedding_1],
 [embedding_0, embedding_3]]
```

---

Concerning the `partition_strategy` argument, you don't have to bother about it. Basically, it allows you to give a list of embedding matrices as `params` instead of 1 matrix, if you have limitations in computation.

So, you could split your embedding matrix of shape `[1000, embedding_size]` in ten matrices of shape `[100, embedding_size]` and pass this list of Variables as `params`. The argument `partition_strategy` handles the distribution of the vocabulary (the 1000 words) among the 10 matrices.

Comment: Where does tf learn the embedding? Is that done in this function too?

Comment: All the embeddings are stored in the embedding matrix ˋparamsˋ, which are learned by gradient descent. With the embedding lookup, only a small portion of the embeddings are updated each time (only the words in the sentences in the batch).

Comment: So this function is only for making it's inner processes easy ?